# Does Elise continue to take damage during Rappel?

Tags: league-of-legends

Elise's `Rappel` ability makes her untargetable and removes her champion from the map for a short duration.  During this time, however, does she continue to take damage from damage over time effects such as `Ignite`?

I ask because I thought I killed one before she cast that, but she lived through it by apparently using it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes Elise continues to take damage from **debuffs applied to her** during *Rappel*. She however does *not* take damage from **Area Targeted** effects during this time. It can therefore be used to 'dodge' many things, just not everything.

The wiki states, and I paraphrase;

> 'Untargetable' refers to champions in a state where targeted spells such as Rammus's Puncturing Taunt and LeBlanc's Sigil of Silence cannot be cast on the untargetable champion, and nontargeted spells such as Karthus's Requiemwill have no effect. Additionally, they cannot be targeted by auto attacks.

It also lists the description for Elise's Rappel skill as;

> Rappel is a point targeted ability with two effects. If an enemy unit is targeted, Elise and her spiderlings will become **untargetable** for about 1 second and will move to the target's location. If Rappel is cast on the ground, Elise and her spiderlings climb into the air and become **untargetable** for up to 2 seconds. While in the air, Elise is granted vision of a large radius around herself, and may target an enemy unit within this radius with Rappel to descend upon them, moving to their location. If the 2 second duration expires, Elise will descend at her original position.

Nothing here mentions anything about single target debuffs that have already been applied, ongoing effects and the like, including but not limited to *leashes* such as Fiddlsticks' or Morgana's, or ongoing damage over time debuffs such as Malzahar's Visions or Summoner Ignite. Therefore it should be assumed they perform normally once applied.

sources:
http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Elise/Ability_Details

http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Untargetable

Comment: for the sake of professionalism i will include a source at a later time, rather busy atm tho.

Comment: It is also worth noting that rappel does not break leash effects (such as fiddles drain or swains slow).

Comment: I'm pretty sure rappel works like Vlad's pool or Fizz's pole, although I don't remember if Fizz's pole lets you avoid dot damage.

Comment: @boiledham Sanguine Pool and Playful/Trickster both do not prevent any damage from previously applied DoTs, however they can be used to avoid their application-- If you use it while the spell is in the air you will avoid the spell while the spell still goes on cooldown

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as another person answered, she will continue to take `DoT` damage, for instance, poison, ignite, blaze, etc. However, skills like `Morgana's Shackle` wouldn't affect her.

Answer (score 0):

Shey may be untargetable, but that does not make Rappel a counter to Zed's Death Mark. If Zed casts Death Mark regardless if he does damage to increase the mark dmg, as lon gas he casts it. If Elise rappels, his mark still explodes, killing her.